# MySql, InnoDB & Null Values

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam, storage-engines

Formerly I was using MyISAM storage engine for MySql and I had defined the combination of three fields to be unique.

Now I have switched to InnoDB, which I assume caused this problem, and now NULL != NULL.

So for the following table:

```
ID (Auto) |  Field_A   | Field_B  | Field_C
```

I can insert (Field_A,Field_B,Field_C) Values(1,2,NULL) (1,2,NULL) (1,2,NULL) infinitely many times.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the business rules, but the first idea would be to set `field_a` and `field_b` as the primary key for the table.  An AUTO_INCREMENT column can be used for a non-primary key column, but the key attribute has to be associated with the auto_increment column:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  ID int auto_increment not null,
  Field_A VARCHAR(45),
  Field_B VARCHAR(45),
  Field_C VARCHAR(45),
  key(ID), --without this, you'll get MySQL ERROR #1075
  primary key(field_a, field_b)
);
```

The other alternative is to add a [unique constraint (MySQL implements them as an index)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX blah_ind USING BTREE ON your_table(field_a, field_b)
```

Comment: I was able to create an index on my auto field, and then drop the primary key.  I then assigned Fields A,B, and C as primary as suggested.  Many thanks!

Comment: @pws5068: Be aware that this will allow duplicates of `field_c` for every unique pair of `field_a` and `field_b` set.

Comment: You're exactly right, that is my intention in this case.  Thanks again.